# Remove String After Determinate String

Tags: c#, .net

I need to remove certain strings after another string within a piece of text.
I have a text file with some URLs and after the URL there is the RESULT of an operation. I need to remove the RESULT of the operation and leave only the URL.

**Example of text:**

```
http://website1.com/something                                        Result: OK(registering only mode is on) 

http://website2.com/something                                    Result: Problems registered 100% (SOMETHING ELSE) Other Strings; 

http://website3.com/something                               Result: error: "Âíèìàíèå, îáíàðóæåíà îøèáêà - Ìåñòî æèòåëüñòâà ñîäåðæèò íåäîïóñòèìûå ê
```

I need to remove all strings starting from **Result:** so the remaining strings have to be:

```
http://website1.com/something

http://website2.com/something

http://website3.com/something
```

Without **Result: ........**

The results are generated randomly so I don't know exactly what there is after **RESULT:**

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is a possible 3-liner, ditto to Oded. Should it be marked "homework" perhaps

Comment: You might want to think about flipping this on its head and extracting the URLs you want to keep rather than removing the results. This may or may not be suitable depending on whether the results ever contain a URL. Having said that, there are a number of perfectly good solutions below! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use regular expressions as per some other answers. Another is just `IndexOf` followed by `Substring`:

```
int resultIndex = text.IndexOf("Result:");
if (resultIndex != -1)
{
    text = text.Substring(0, resultIndex);
}
```

Personally I tend to find that if I can get away with just a couple of *very simple and easy to understand* string operations, I find that easier to get right than using regex. Once you start going into real patterns (at least 3 of these, then one of those) then regexes become a lot more useful, of course.

Comment: It doesn't remove the whitespaces after ActionX. In this case, maybe it would be better to look for the first whitespace, and then take the substring.

Comment: @LaGrandMere: I see no indication in the question that that's required. "I've to remove all string starting from Result:" If that's the aim, I'd trim it *afterwards*. There's nothing in the question which states that it won't actually be "Action Foo 1" for example.

Comment: You're right, the example given by OP made me think there was ActionX, multiple whitespaces, Result: then anything else, but the question asked is clear.

Comment: Thanks guys but the problem is in the file "ACTION1" and etc is an example, this files will be generate random,is a list of websites and after there is the status like "Result: ......." I wanna delete every strings after RESULT and see only the website link.

Comment: @user1643768: Right, which is why my code doesn't care about "ACTION1" at all. It does exactly what you asked for: removing "Result:" and everything that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - by using string.Replace

```
var pattern = "Result:";
var lineContainYourValue = "jdfhkjsdfhsdf Result:ljksdfljh"; //I want replace test
lineContainYourValue.Replace(pattern,"");
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, It Works but delete just the word **RESULT**.I've to remove every character after **RESULT**. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1643768

Comment: In this case, the pattern should be `var pattern = "Result:(.*)$"`, and it will cut anything beginning with `Result:`

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "Action2 Result: Problems registered 100% (SOMETHING ELSE) Other Strings; ";
string pattern = "^(Action[0-9]*) (.*)$";
string replacement = "$1";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

You use `$1` to keep the match ActionXX.

Comment: This will give you, e.g. `"Action1 "`.  I think you could move the `)` to before the space to make it result in `"Action1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex for this.

Example:

```
var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Result:(.)*");
var result = r.Replace("Action Result:1231231", "");
```

Then you will have "Action" in the result.

Answer (score 0):

A Linq approach:

```
IEnumerable<String> result = System.IO.File
    .ReadLines(path)
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith("Action") && l.Contains("Result"))
    .Select(l => l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf("Result")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this perhaps?

```
string line;
using ( var reader = new StreamReader ( File.Open ( @"C:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open ) ) )
   using ( var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open( @"C:\Temp\test.edited.txt", FileMode.CreateNew ) ))
       while ( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null )
          if(!line.StartsWith("Result:")) sw.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx for this kind of processing.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private string ParseString(string originalString)
{
    string pattern = ".*(?=Result:.*)";
    Match match = Regex.Match(originalString, pattern);
    return match.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current example, where you want only the website, regex match the spaces.

```
var fileLine = "http://example.com/sub/     random text";
Regex regexPattern = new Regex("(.*?)\\s");
var websiteMatch = regexPattern.Match(fileLine).Groups[1].ToString();
Debug.Print("!" + websiteMatch + "!");
```

Repeating for each line in your text file.  Regex explained: .* matches anything, ? makes the match ungreedy, (brackets) puts the match into a group, \\s  matches whitespace.